# Javascript double-click does not work in IE9 and IE11

Tags: javascript, html, css, ajax, double-click

In my javascript code, single-click opens link in new tab and double-click opens  light-box.  It works ok in all browsers except in IE9 and IE11.
In my first code, both single-click and double-click work but for single-click, IE gives message, "allow pop-up?"  I want IE to open the link in new tab w/o the message just like the other browsers.
In my second code, single-click works as I want but the second click of double- click in IE gets ignored and ends up working as single-click.  Can something be done to remove the issue - either in the first code or in the second code - that I am perhaps missing?

First Code:

```
                       $('div[id^="jzl_"].short').click(function(e) {
                              var $this = $(this);
                              var currentID = e.target.id;

                              if ($this.hasClass('clicked')) {
                                     $this.removeClass('clicked');
                                     $.colorbox({
                                            href : "getInfo1.php?id=" + currentID,
                                            overlayClose : false,
                                            top : "16%"
                                     });
                                     //$.colorbox({ overlayClose: false });
                                     //alert("Double click");
                                     //here is your code for double click
                              } else {
                                     $this.addClass('clicked');
                                     setTimeout(function() {
                                            if ($this.hasClass('clicked')) {
                                                   $this.removeClass('clicked');
                                                   //                                 alert("Just one click!");
                                                   var jobSite = window.open('', '_blank');
                                                   sleep(1000);
                                                   var redirct = getPage(currentID);
                                                   sleep(1000);
                                                   jobSite.location = redirct;
                                                   //var redirct = getPage(currentID);
                                                   //window.open(redirct, '_newtab' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 999999));
                                            }
                                     }, 500);
                              }
                       });
```

Second Code:

```
                       $('div[id^="jzl_"].short').click(function(e) {
                              var $this = $(this);
                              var currentID = e.target.id;
                              var jobSite = window.open('', '_blank');
                              if ($this.hasClass('clicked')) {
                                     $this.removeClass('clicked');
                                     $.colorbox({
                                            href : "getInfo1.php?id=" + currentID,
                                            overlayClose : false,
                                            top : "16%"
                                     });
                                     //$.colorbox({ overlayClose: false });
                                     //alert("Double click");
                                     //here is your code for double click
                              } else {
                                     $this.addClass('clicked');
                                     setTimeout(function() {
                                            if ($this.hasClass('clicked')) {
                                                   $this.removeClass('clicked');
                                                   //                                 alert("Just one click!");
                                                   var redirct = getPage(currentID);
                                                   jobSite.location = redirct;
                                                   //var redirct = getPage(currentID);
                                                   //window.open(redirct, '_newtab' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 999999));
                                            }
                                     }, 500);
                              }
                       });
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use both .click() and .dblclick() instead of testing whether or not the element has the `clicked` class. So here is the new code:

```
$('div[id^="jzl_"].short').dblclick(function(e) {

var $this = $(this);
var currentID = e.target.id;

$.colorbox({
href : "getInfo1.php?id=" + currentID,
overlayClose : false,
top : "16%"
});

//$.colorbox({ overlayClose: false });
//alert("Double click");
//here is your code for double click

});



$('div[id^="jzl_"].short').click(function(e) {

 var $this = $(this);
 var currentID = e.target.id;

 var jobSite = window.open('', '_blank');
 var redirct = getPage(currentID);
jobSite.location = redirct;

//var redirct = getPage(currentID);
//window.open(redirct, '_newtab' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 999999));

});
```

Comment: Ola, dbl-click in your code ends up working as single-click not only in IE but also in FF and Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

This solution should work:

```
var t = []; //timeout array
$('div[id^="jzl_"].short')
    .on('click', function(e) {
        var $this = $(this),
            currentID = e.target.id;

        // put each click in timeout array
        t[t.length] = setTimeout(function() {
            t = []; //reset timeout array
            alert('clicked: ' + currentID);

            //your code here

        }, 500);
    })
    .on('dblclick', function (e) {

        //cancel 2 timeouts and reset timeout array
        clearTimeout(t[0]);
        clearTimeout(t[1]);
        t = [];

        var $this = $(this),
            currentID = e.target.id;

        window.open('http://google.com', '_blank');
    });
```

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/tvL07phr/2/

Comment: you switched `click to open alert` and `dblclick to open url in new tab`.  I switched it back for `click to open url in new tab` and `dblclick to open alert` and it ended up giving the same result as my first code.  If you want I can post my codes below your code.

Comment: yes.  in fact if you run your fiddle in IE9 or IE11, single-click will invoke IE message "Allow pop-up?" instead of opening google.com in new tab.

Comment: But the click/dblclick logic works, right? Except that IE displays the allow popup prompt due to the setTimeout. Popup blockers are invoked when the popup is not triggered by user events. Technically, the popup is triggered by user event (click in our case) but somehow for IE, the user event trigger is lost because of the setTimeout. I'll find a solution to fix that.

Comment: I tried to find a way to prevent IE popup blocker to block click event inside setTimeout without success. I researched MSDN (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537632(v=vs.85).aspx) and found out that "If you use the setTimeout() method within a click event, the pop-up window will not be launched." So there you go, there's no way around it. Why not just reverse the logic as I initially suggested - open the popup on dblclick event and do the other one on click event? Opening the popup on dblclick event will not be blocked as it is not inside setTimeout.

Comment: yes, what I need is when click is used to open url in new tab, IE should not display the allow popup prompt.

Comment: But as I said, Microsoft documented it that the popup will be blocked if user event is initiated inside setTimeout. So it looks like there is really no way to get around it.

Comment: Look at my 'Second Code' in my OP, click works in IE w/o displaying the allow popup prompt, but dblclick does not open alert, it also opens URL???

Comment: The popup in your second code is not blocked because the window.open() is not inside setTimeout. The problem with that is you open the popup regardless if event is click or dblclick. So there will always be a popup. Is that behavior ok for you?

Comment: No, that behavior is not ok for me.  Still thinking if there may be a way to cancel single-click, popup, or window.open() if there is double-click???